# React navbar not working properly showing error

Tags: reactjs, router

i was trying to build a navbar in react .the functionality was to show the bar on button click and withdrow it again on button click . But the functionality is not working showing this error : " Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')" in console.

my code here:

const menu = document.getElementById('menu');

```
const closeBar = () =>{
    menu.style.top = '-100vh';
}

const openBar = () =>{
    menu.style.top = '17%';
}
```

Get Started
                        
                        
                    
                     
                        
                       
                            
                            Home
                            
                            Courses
                            
                            Blog
                            
                            Dashboard
                            
                            Login

Comment: show your html code (menu and script tags)

Comment: This is not exactly react code, you are not supposed to access properties like that. Most probably you  are looking for useRef function,

Comment: so i can't do the functionality in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react you work declaratively, this means that you "indicates" to react how the page should look and react takes care of do it, this why you dont manipulate the doom directly in most of the cases. To do that, you could do:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [showNavbar, setShowNavbar] = useState(true);

  const handleOnClick = (e) => {
    setShowNavbar(!showNavbar);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {showNavbar && <Navbar />}
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Toggle navbar</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this shows/hide the Navbar component when the button is clicked